# GridView Row Update SQL Server parameter not defined

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

[image]

Below is my method to update the row once the update button is clicked. My SQL Server stored procedure is expecting the existing company name before it has been updated, the new company name and whether it exists or not. The bold part is where it is breaking. When I select edit, I want to parse in the current value in the company name row before I hit update.

```
protected void CompanyTable_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[updateCompanyName]", cn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        GridViewRow row = CompanyTable.SelectedRow;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentCompanyName", CompanyTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewCompanyName", CompanyInputTextBox.Text).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        SqlParameter objisExists = new SqlParameter("@isExists", SqlDbType.Int);
        objisExists.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(objisExists);

        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();

        int isExists = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@isExists"].Value.ToString());

        if (isExists == 0)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "111", "AddCompanySuccess();", true);
        }
        else if (isExists == 1)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "111", "CompanyExistsValidation();", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Stored procedure parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateCompanyName] 
    @CurrentCompanyName VARCHAR(50),
    @NewCompanyName VARCHAR(50),
    @IsExists INT = 0 OUT
```

My update in SQL:

```
DECLARE @CompanyID INT

SELECT @CompanyID = CompanyID 
FROM company 
WHERE companyname = @CurrentCompanyName

BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT CompanyName FROM company 
               WHERE companyname = @NewCompanyName )
    BEGIN
         SET @IsExists = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN   
        UPDATE COMPANY
        SET CompanyName = @NewCompanyName 
        WHERE companyid = @CompanyID

        SET @IsExists = 0
    END
END

PRINT @isexists
```

Comment: I think if you use `Add` instead of `AddWithValue` you might figure out the problem.

Comment: Havent managed to get it working by changing the AddWithValue to Add. Any more hints or help?

Comment: Maybe try removing the square brackets from the stored proc? I don't think you need them. Are you getting an exception?

Comment: the square brackets would not make a difference. It works if i execute in SQL, its an issue with the connection between the C# application and parsing that one parameter in.